# Merge multiple flv files - runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flv, flvplayback

I have multiple FLV files, and during run time based on the user's selection i need to combine and merge multiple FLV files into single FLV file and play to the user.

so far we are using as playlist with different flv files, but now we need to change the process.

Can any one know how can I merge different FLV files during run time and play/download the file in single shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While in theory you could use something like [this](http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/updated-flv-encoder-alchem/) to encode an flv at runtime I wouldn't suggest it.

Your best bet would be to start playing the first video and then buffer a second video in the background. That way your second video is ready to play once the first video has dispatched its complete event.